# Como fazer um dendograma a partir de variáveis qualitativas no R?

Tags: r

Bom dia. Por favor, preciso de um script ou explicação de como fazer um dendograma/cluster a partir de variáveis qualitativas. Eu vi em algum lugar que é possível fazer aquilo usando a saída do ANACOR, mas não faço ideia de quais valores pegar.

Comment: Crie primeiro uma tabela de contingência e depois veja o `help("hclust")`. Mais ou menos isto: `data(Cars93, package = "MASS"); tabela_cont <- xtabs(~ Type + Origin, Cars93); d <- dist(tabela_cont); hc <- hclust(d); plot(hc)`
`

Comment: Muito obrigado Rubi. O exemplo é perfeito! Abraços